# Adding an Object of class to an array of the same class C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, for-loop, arraylist, foreach

**Hello all**
I try to convert a group of ٍStrings to a class, and then add these elements to an **array or list** of the same class

**problem**
*Everything is fine, only when one element is added does it change all the values in the array to the same values as the last element*

**TxtCookie.Text :**

1=|257|9.5|1|true|true|true|true|1-From Web, 2=|259|11.5|7|false|false|false|false|232-From Web, 3=|261|9.5|5|true|false|true|true|-From Web, 4=|267|9.5|1|true|true|true|true|-From Web

**This code :**

```
        //Get The Value from Text Box To list of Strings
        string[] lst = TxtCookie.Text.Split(',');
        //Divide each element into a set of values
        var D = (from a in lst select a.Split('|')).ToList();

        //Define an object from the class
        TblInvoiceContent tblInvoiceContent = new TblInvoiceContent();
        //Define an List from the class
        List<TblInvoiceContent> TBLIC = new List<TblInvoiceContent>();

        //Here I take the values and configure them according to the class structure
        foreach (var item in D)
        {
            tblInvoiceContent.ItremID = Convert.ToInt32(item[1]);
            tblInvoiceContent.SilingPrice = Convert.ToDouble(item[2]);
            tblInvoiceContent.Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(item[3]);
            tblInvoiceContent.mayonnaise = Convert.ToBoolean(item[4]);
            tblInvoiceContent.ketchup = Convert.ToBoolean(item[5]);
            tblInvoiceContent.Hot = Convert.ToBoolean(item[6]);
            tblInvoiceContent.garlic = Convert.ToBoolean(item[7]);
            tblInvoiceContent.Reqomindition = item[8].ToString();
            //Here I add the item to the list
            TBLIC.Add(tblInvoiceContent);

        }
        //Here I am displaying the list items
        GridView1.DataSource = TBLIC;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

**Result :**

[image: All Items Of The list is the Same !!, in forech it read all defrint D items]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you only ever create one instance of your object:

```
TblInvoiceContent tblInvoiceContent = new TblInvoiceContent();
```

Then in the loop you modify the instance each time and re-add it to the list again.

Move the instance creation into the loop:

```
foreach (var item in D)
{
    TblInvoiceContent tblInvoiceContent = new TblInvoiceContent();

    tblInvoiceContent.ItremID = Convert.ToInt32(item[1]);
    tblInvoiceContent.SilingPrice = Convert.ToDouble(item[2]);
    tblInvoiceContent.Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(item[3]);
    tblInvoiceContent.mayonnaise = Convert.ToBoolean(item[4]);
    tblInvoiceContent.ketchup = Convert.ToBoolean(item[5]);
    tblInvoiceContent.Hot = Convert.ToBoolean(item[6]);
    tblInvoiceContent.garlic = Convert.ToBoolean(item[7]);
    tblInvoiceContent.Reqomindition = item[8].ToString();

    TBLIC.Add(tblInvoiceContent);
}
```

That way each time the loop iterates you would create a new instance of the object.

Answer (score 1):

```
    //Get The Value from Text Box To list of Strings
    string[] lst = TxtCookie.Text.Split(',');
    //Divide each element into a set of values
    var D = (from a in lst select a.Split('|')).ToList();


    //Define an List from the class
    List<TblInvoiceContent> TBLIC = new List<TblInvoiceContent>();

    //Here I take the values and configure them according to the class structure
    foreach (var item in D)
    {
        //CALL IT HERE Define an object from the class
        TblInvoiceContent tblInvoiceContent = new TblInvoiceContent();

        tblInvoiceContent.ItremID = Convert.ToInt32(item[1]);
        tblInvoiceContent.SilingPrice = Convert.ToDouble(item[2]);
        tblInvoiceContent.Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(item[3]);
        tblInvoiceContent.mayonnaise = Convert.ToBoolean(item[4]);
        tblInvoiceContent.ketchup = Convert.ToBoolean(item[5]);
        tblInvoiceContent.Hot = Convert.ToBoolean(item[6]);
        tblInvoiceContent.garlic = Convert.ToBoolean(item[7]);
        tblInvoiceContent.Reqomindition = item[8].ToString();
        //Here I add the item to the list
        TBLIC.Add(tblInvoiceContent);

    }
    //Here I am displaying the list items
    GridView1.DataSource = TBLIC;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```